Performance of subqueries vs joins with grouping in SQL Server
I'm not a database expert, so decided to ask the community about the difference between the following queries:
DECLARE @today date = '2024-08-01'
SELECT (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM([trx].[Amount]), 0.0)
        FROM [Transactions] AS [trx]
        LEFT JOIN [Invoices] AS [i] ON [i].[Id] = [trx].[InvoiceId]
        WHERE [p].[Id] = [trx].[PurchaseId] AND [trx].[Status] = 0 AND [trx].[Type] IN (1, 2) AND [trx].[PurchaseId] IS NOT NULL AND [i].[DueDate] < @today AND [i].[Flag] = CAST(0 AS bit)
    ) - (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM([pp].[PaymentAmount]), 0.0)
        FROM [Transactions] AS [trx]
        LEFT JOIN [Invoices] AS [i] ON [i].[Id] = [trx].[InvoiceId]
        INNER JOIN [PaymentParts] AS [pp] ON [pp].[TransactionId] = [trx].[Id]
        WHERE [p].[Id] = [trx].[PurchaseId] AND [trx].[Status] = 0 AND [trx].[Type] IN (1, 2) AND [trx].[PurchaseId] IS NOT NULL AND [i].[DueDate] < @today AND [i].[Flag] = CAST(0 AS bit)
    )
FROM [Purchases] AS [p]

-- returning I/O statistics
-- (862419 rows affected)
-- Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 19, logical reads 106192, physical reads 12151, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 94041, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Transactions'. Scan count 2, logical reads 639166, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 318062, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 2, logical reads 117262, physical reads 3, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 85754, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Purchases'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3973, physical reads 2, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 4060, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'PaymentParts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 193222, physical reads 4, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 193671, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

-- (1 row affected)

and
DECLARE @today date = '2024-08-01'
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM([trx].[UnpaidAmount])
    FROM ( 
        SELECT [trx].[Amount] - SUM([pp].[PaymentAmount]) AS [UnpaidAmount]
        FROM [Transactions] AS [trx]
        LEFT JOIN [Invoices] AS [i] ON [i].[Id] = [trx].[InvoiceId]
        LEFT JOIN [PaymentParts] AS [pp] ON [pp].[TransactionId] = [trx].[Id]
        WHERE [p].[Id] = [trx].[PurchaseId] AND [trx].[Status] = 0 AND [trx].[Type] IN (1, 2) AND [trx].[PurchaseId] IS NOT NULL AND [i].[DueDate] < @today AND [i].[Flag] = CAST(0 AS bit)
        GROUP BY [trx].[Id], [trx].[Amount]
    ) AS [trx]
)
FROM [Purchases] AS [p]

-- returning I/O statistics
-- Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

-- (862419 rows affected)
-- Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 39, logical reads 345144, physical reads 40885, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 304259, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Transactions'. Scan count 1, logical reads 319583, physical reads 6090, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 300961, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 1, logical reads 58631, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 1454, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'Purchases'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3973, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
-- Table 'PaymentParts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 193222, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 192870, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

-- (1 row affected)

As you might have guessed, they have different execution plans:

The 1st query makes joins on the [Transactions] & [Invoices] tables 2 times
The 2nd one in its turn makes some aggregations and loads a lot of data to the [tempdb]

In terms of response time, they take about the same amount of time. So, my question is which query is more performant from your perspective and which one will you use?

Obligatory: Race your own horses. If you're saying they're the same speed, then this becomes an opinion-based question. The "best" approach would depend on your coding style, how fast your I/O is, how likely it is that the data will always be in memory, how bottlenecked tempdb is, what happens under higher concurrency, etc. This isn't the place to ask about what people like better.

Assuming that they're both of an acceptable speed then personally I would pick whichever query is the easiest to understand an maintain.

Indexing and performance testing are both subjects that are more complicated than they may seem. See covering index for a little more knowledge about one technique.

A few observations: (1) With the [i].[DueDate] < @today and [i].[Flag] = CAST(0 AS bit) conditions, your LEFT JOIN effectively becomes an INNER JOIN. (2) The [p].[Id] = [trx].[PurchaseId] appears to allow multiple transactions per purchase., the ON [i].[Id] = [trx].[InvoiceId] join condition appears to limit a transaction to at most one invoice, while ON [pp].[TransactionId] = [trx].[Id] allows a transaction to have multiple payment parts, so the join structure seems sound. (with no multiple independent one-to-many joins). (3)  One subquery appears to be a subset of the other.

... Given the above observations, I see no reason why you shouldn't opt for the single-combined subquery. Why make two trips to the store when you can get everything in a single trip?  You might also be able to structure your query as a 3-level nested query - Purchases at the outer level, Transactions and Invoices at the middle level, and PaymentParts at the bottom level.  This way, you need not use GROUP BY to consolidate duplicate transaction amounts.

Since the work needed to retrieve a transaction is a subset of the work needed to retrieve the transaction plus its payments, I see no reason why you should not prefer the single combined subquery. I tend to rank the cost of storage accesses over the cost of simple in-memory operations, like group-by. However, the final decision should be based on your performance test results. Data caching may mitigate the multiple table references.
As an alternative to the two queries you posted, you might also be able to structure your query as a 3-level nested query with:

Purchases at the outer level,
Transactions and Invoices at the middle level, and
PaymentParts at the bottom level.

This way, you need not use a GROUP BY to consolidate duplicate transaction amounts. Each or the rows retrieved are only referenced once.
Something like:
DECLARE @today date = '2024-08-01'
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(ua.UnpaidAmount)
    FROM ( 
        SELECT
            trx.Amount - (
                SELECT COALESCE(SUM(pp.PaymentAmount), 0.0)
                FROM PaymentParts AS pp
                WHERE pp.TransactionId = trx.Id
            ) AS UnpaidAmount
        FROM Transactions AS trx
        LEFT JOIN Invoices AS i ON i.Id = trx.InvoiceId
        WHERE p.Id = trx.PurchaseId
        AND trx.Status = 0
        AND trx.Type IN (1, 2)
        AND trx.PurchaseId IS NOT NULL
        AND i.DueDate < @today
        AND i.Flag = CAST(0 AS bit)
    ) AS ua
)
FROM Purchases AS p

The above can also be restructured using CROSS APPLYs.
DECLARE @today date = '2024-08-01'
SELECT SUM(ua.UnpaidAmount)
FROM Purchases AS p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT trx.Amount - sp.SumPaymentAmounts AS UnpaidAmount
    FROM Transactions AS trx
    INNER JOIN Invoices AS i
        ON i.Id = trx.InvoiceId
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(pp.PaymentAmount), 0.0) AS SumPaymentAmounts
        FROM PaymentParts AS pp
        WHERE pp.TransactionId = trx.Id
    ) AS sp
    WHERE p.Id = trx.PurchaseId
    AND trx.Status = 0
    AND trx.Type IN (1, 2)
    AND trx.PurchaseId IS NOT NULL
    AND i.DueDate < @today
    AND i.Flag = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS ua

